# Trouble with < in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-3.5

Ok so I have this string thats going to be an attribute of script tag:

```
path = "<%= this.ResolveUrl('~/" + path + "') %>";
```

only problem is when I dynamically generate the tag it turns into:

```
<script src="&lt;%= this.ResolveUrl('~/Scripts/jquery.js') %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I don't want the `&lt;` to be there I want an < to be there...

How can I fix this to generate the < instead of `&lt;`

I have already tried escaping it by using `@"&lt;"` and that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of file is this in? Can you post more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following line:

```
path = this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.js");
```

**Tip:** Since you are using jQuery you should have a look at the [Google AJAX Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/). Its basically jQuery and a lot of other AJAX APIs hosted on Google's CDN (so you don't have to). Include it on your page by doing something like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
        this,
        typeof(Page),
        "jQuery",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js");
```

or simply

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```